# python 3.5 copying excel sheet make loss of data

Tags: python, excel, copy

below is the code I`m writing. But the result new.xls is broken and images and text in source file hasn`t been copied.The source file's text data are not links they are just text values.Is this something I can`t do with it or what?.thanks in advance.
outline of the code is simple.Just coping some sheets and edit some cells, then insert it into another workbook.

```
def extract_xls():
f=open('extract_sample.txt', 'r', encoding='shift_jis')
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()

old_book=xlrd.open_workbook('./frame.xlsx', on_demand=True)
ob=copy(old_book)

logic_name=''
physical_name=''
return_type=''
sheets=[]
sheets.append(deepcopy(ob.get_sheet(0)))
sheets.append(deepcopy(ob.get_sheet(1)))
sheets.append(deepcopy(ob.get_sheet(2)))
demo_sheet=deepcopy(ob.get_sheet(2))
ind=3
for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        ar=line.split(' ')
        if len(ar)==3:
            logic_name=ar[0]
            return_type=ar[1]
            physical_name=ar[2]
            demo_sheet.set_name(str(ind)+'.'+physical_name)
            demo_sheet.write(2, 14, logic_name)
            demo_sheet.write(2, 30, logic_name)
            ind+=1
            sheets.append(demo_sheet)
            demo_sheet=deepcopy(ob.get_sheet(2))
lines=None

new_book=xlwt.Workbook()
new_book._Workbook__worksheets=sheets
new_book.save('./new.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the Excel file a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file?

I can read and write CSV files with Python with no problem - make sure the file is only one Excel sheet (i.e. not multiple Excel sheets).

Maybe this would solve your issue.

Comment: Probably I wasn`t clear enough. the sheets of the source excel file has some templates like group some cell and images on some sheets.isn`t it possible to convert this kind of excel into csv?